# How to filter serializers.SlugRelatedField queryset using model field

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am having trouble filtering the possible options for a SlugRelatedField using the `queryset` parameter.  Here is my serializer

```
class AttendeeProfileSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    """
    Profile Serializer
    """
    user = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='username', queryset=User.objects.all())
    module = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='id', queryset=AttendeeModule.objects.all())
    picture = serializers.ImageField(allow_empty_file=False, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = AttendeeProfile
        fields = (
            'user', 'module', 'title', 'company', 'email', 'picture', 'is_active', 'created'
        )
```

I would like to filter the module field though, a la `serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='id', queryset=AttendeeModule.objects.filter(module__app='module__app')` or something similar where each module belongs to an app.

I imagine I need to provide more context to the serializer through the view?  Should I be overriding a method on the view?  I've tried but I'm still new to Django rest framework and it's giving me a lot of trouble

The view is

```
class AttendeesList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    """

    """
    queryset = AttendeeProfile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AttendeeProfileSerializer
```

And using this route

```
url(r'^apps/(?P<url_name>[a-z][a-z0-9]+)/modules/(?P<module_id>[0-9]+)/attendees$',
    views.AttendeesList.as_view(),
    name='attendees-list'),
```

Comment: Hey, did you ever figure out if this is possible? I wanted to ask this exact question!

Comment: Sorry I wasn't able to figure out how to do this, it wasn't as bad as I thought though.  My reasoning for doing this was to improve performance, firstly because the DRF Browsable API renders the whole queryset on GET which seems wasteful (I want a small subset), however I've found the large majority of users will be interacting with the API through JSON and the queryset is not evaluated on these get requests.

Secondly I wanted to use this for validation.  In the end I found it better to implement validate_field methods on the serializers for this.  Still curious if there's a better way.

Comment: No problem, thanks for getting back. I managed to create a solution that worked for me, but it's definitely not tuned for performance so may not be relevant to you. I explained the solution in my answer to this similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30632992/slugrelatedfield-queryset/35518156#35518156

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I found a solution to my ancient question:

```
class SlugRelatedModuleField(SlugRelatedField):

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = self.queryset
        if hasattr(self.root, 'app_id'):
            queryset = queryset.filter(module__app_id=self.root.app_id)
        return queryset

class AttendeeProfileSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.app_id = kwargs.pop('app_id')
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    module = SlugRelatedModuleField(
        slug_field='id', 
        queryset=AttendeeModule.objects.all()
    )

    class Meta:
        model = AttendeeProfile
        fields = ('user', 'module', 'title', 'company', 'email', 'picture', 'is_active', 'created')
```

This assigns an `app_id` attribute on the parent/root serializer, and the SlugRelatedModuleField inspects the parent to filter the queryset.  Tada.

Comment: will it help with not caching the entire queryset??

Comment: I'm not certain exactly what you mean, but this should result in a much smaller queryset being used by the SlugRelatedField.  Rest framework uses the queryset to render a list of choices in the browsable API, and this can be quite expensive to query and render every row in your database (depending on the size if your table).

Comment: So queryset usually get cached, I wanted to know if I do a filter operation with get_queryset function , will it remove the entire table from cache?

Comment: what is app_id??

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, app_id is just the id of the object that I want to use for filtering the queryset in the SlugRelatedField.  Regarding caching, if you modify the QuerySet at all it should always invalidate the underlying cache because the return value will be different. Even if it isn't different because, for example, you want exclude certain rows by a value but no rows have that value, the QuerySet doesn't know the return is the same, all it knows is that your query has changed and it will have to make a call to the database to find out.

Comment: `self.context.get('request', None)` can be used to access `request` object here.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I needed access to `request.user` as well for filtering, for which I see no solution above, so here is a sample code:

```
class MyFieldName(serializers.SlugRelatedField):
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
        request = self.context.get('request', None)
        if not request.user.is_superuser:
            queryset = queryset.filter(user=request.user)
        return queryset

class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    organization = MyFieldName(slug_field='slug')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the [`context` parameter](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context) of the serializer.

```py
class SlugRelatedModuleField(SlugRelatedField):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset.filter(module__app_id=self.context["app_id"])
```

Context can be set in a view(set) like this:

```py
class AttendeeProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = AttendeeProfile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AttendeeProfileSerializer

    def get_serializer_context(self) -> Dict[str, Any]:
        return {
            **super().get_serializer_context(),
            "app_id": self.request.data.get("app_id")
        }
```