# SlugRelatedField queryset

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I am struggling to figure out the queryset for SlugRelatedField.
My data is such that I have a bunch of `Object` instances that belong to a `Project`. A project has a unique 'top' `Object`. `Object`s can have the same name only if they below to different `Project`s.

```
class Object(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey('Project', null=False, related_name='objs')
    name = models.TextField(null=False, db_index=True)
    ....
    class Meta:
        index_together = unique_together = ('project', 'name')

class Project(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), null=False, related_name='+')
    name = models.TextField(null=False)
    top = models.OneToOneField(Object, null=True, related_name='+')
    ....

class ObjectSerializer(NonNullSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Object
        fields = ('name',)

class ProjectSerializer(NonNullSerializer):
    objs = ObjectSerializer(many=True, required=False)
    top = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='name', queryset=Object.objects.filter(????))

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'objs', 'top')
```

What is my queryset going to look like for `top` if I want to find only only the one `Object` that belongs to the correct `Project`? In other words, how to deserialize this:

```
[{
    'name' : 'Project1',
    'objs' : [{
        'name': 'One'
    }],
    'top': 'One'
},
{
    'name' : 'Project2',
    'objs' : [{
        'name': 'One'
    }],
    'top': 'One'     <-- This should point to One under Project2, not One under Project1
}]
```

Comment: Hey, did you ever figure out if this is possible? I wanted to ask this exact question!

Comment: I did. I has custom create/update methods, so `objs` get created first, then `top` gets resolved. But I abandoned this approach altogether, the implementation looked too convoluted, just wasn't flowing nicely - what if `top` is not valid? to resolve `top` you need a db call. At the end I ended up with two REST calls, one creates the main object, the second creates the `objs`. Overall, handling hierarchical data is a major pain, and since I can update a single piece of data at any level, multiple REST calls seemed to handle this better.

Comment: Hey, thanks for getting back. I've fixed mine this morning to work, taking what sounds like a similar approach to yours. It's valid, I think, but still convoluted :) (I'd be happy to share the details if you'd be interested) Agreed that hierarchical data is a pain. I've used a few of my own solutions that I could make generic and create a plugin for. Cheers again!

Comment: Yes, you should post your solution as an answer below.

Comment: OK, I've had a stab - let me know what you think

Answer (score 4):

I was just revisiting my own question on this topic when I was lead back to here, so here's a way of achieving this (I think).

```
class ObjectSerializer(NonNullSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Object
        fields = ('name',)

class TopSerializerField(SlugRelatedField):
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = self.queryset
        if hasattr(self.root, 'project_id'):
            queryset = queryset.filter(project_id=project_id)
        return queryset

class ProjectSerializer(NonNullSerializer):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.project_id = kwargs.pop('project_id')
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    # I've needed this workaround for some cases...
    # def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    #    """When `many=True` is provided then we need to attach the project_id attribute to the ListSerializer instance"""
    #    project_id = kwargs.get('project_id')
    #    serializer = super(ProjectSerializer, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    #    setattr(serializer, 'project_id', project_id)
    #    return serializer

    objs = ObjectSerializer(many=True, required=False)
    top = TopSerializerField(slug_field='name', queryset=Object.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'objs', 'top')
```

When you go to deserialize the data, it would search for objects that belong to the correct project defined on the serializer.

Answer (score 2):

I have a solution that solves this problem in my case, which I will try to explain here.

The problem, abstracted:

Suppose I have a hierarchy with `Foo` as the top-level objects, each associated with several `Bar`s:

```
class Foo(Model):
    pass

class Bar(Model):
    bar_text = CharField()
    foo = ForeignKey(Foo, related_name='bars')
```

Then I can use `SlugRelatedField` trivially for read only serializations of `Foo`, by which I mean the serializer:

```
class FooSerializer(ModelSerializer):
     bars = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='bar_text', 
                                         many=True, read_only=True)
     class Meta:
         model = Foo
         fields = ('bars',)
```

will produce serializations like:

```
{ 'bars' : [<bar_text>, <bar_text>, ...] }
```

However, this is read only. To allow writing, I have to provide a queryset class attribute outside of any methods. The problem is, because we have a `Foo->Bar` hierarchy, we don't *know* what the queryset is outside of any request. We would like to be able to override a `get_queryset()` method, but none seems to exist. So we can't use `SlugRelatedField`. What horribly hacky way can we fix it?

My Solution:

First, add an @property to the Foo model and put this property in the serializer:

In `models.py`:

```
class Foo(Model):
    @property
    def bar_texts(self):
        return [bar.bar_text for bar in self.bars.all()]
```

In `serializers.py`:

```
class FooSerializer(ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
         model = Foo
         fields = ('bar_texts',)
```

This allows for the bar texts to be serialized as before, but we still can't write (we can try - the framework won't reject it but it will hit an exception when trying to save the bar_texts attribute of a `Foo`)

So, the hacky part - fix `perform_create()` in the `Foo` list view.

```
class FooList:
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        # The serializer contains the bar_text field, which we want, but doesn't correspond
        # to a writeable attribute of Foo. Extract the strings and save the Foo. Use pop with a default arg in case bar_texts isn't in the serialized data
        bar_texts = serializer.validated_data.pop('bar_texts', [])

        # Save the Foo object; it currently has no Bars associated with it
        foo = serializer.save()

        # Now add the Bars to the database
        for bar_text in bar_texts:
            foo.bars.create(bar_text=bar_text)
```

I hope that makes sense. It certainly works for me, but I have get to find any glaring bugs with it